# AlpineJs/Laravel - How to take value of tag and pass it to controller

Tags: laravel-blade, alpine.js

I am new to working with Alpine JS and Laravel. I want to take the value of `:value` and pass it to a controller so I can do a query with it. Is it possible to query and display the data asynchronously via alpine? Or would adding a button to display the data with blade be the only way?

Here is my code

```html
<template x-model="Date" :key="Date.id" x-for="Date in Dates">
    <!-- Value I want to use in query -->
    <input x-model="Three" name="CheckThing1" type="radio" :value='Date.id' />
</template>
```

Comment: With Alpine.js you have the same possibilities as JavaScript: submit a form, call an address with parameters in the query string or do a fetch.
Perhaps what you are looking for is Livewire.

Answer (score 0):

Let's be honest, this is a rather vague and undirected question. There's multiple ways you can make backend calls, but it seems you don't even know where to start. Therefore here are a few options you can consider:

- You can use [Laravel Livewire](https://livewire.laravel.com/docs), which is like using Laravel Blade syntax with direct connection to the backend (Livewire handles the asynchronous connection).
- You can use a `form` that takes the values of your input(s) using a `GET` request, which is a common tactic for filterering.
- You can use typical AlpineJS [data object](https://alpinejs.dev/globals/alpine-data) in combination with a [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest) or using the [fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch).

  - You can perform the above even without an AlpineJS data object, instead you can use an event listener in the local JavaScript to trigger the request.
- If for some reason you're using jQuery (you shouldn't be mixing frameworks unless absolutely necessary) you can use its [$.ajax wrapper](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/).

I hope to have helped you on your way, and I'd be happy to answer more questions.